# Fine Uploader processing order

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm sending images that are grouped together on the server.

Sending the first image, the onSubmit checks if a id is set client side and if not the server creates one. This is then send back to the client via the onComplete responseJSON and is then ready for the then next onSubmit.

However if I upload 4 images at once, currently fine uploader fires 4 submits then 4 completes putting these images in to 4 separate groups.

Is there a way to order the process as submit, complete, submit, complete and so on?

Comment: From what i understand you want the functions to be called synchronously. Did you try using `Promise` ?

Comment: "Is there a way to order the process as submit, complete, submit, complete and so on?" Only if you wait to submit the next file until the previous one completes

Comment: @RayNicholus is that possible in fine uploader or do you mean physically? Thanks